# aws athena command not working on ec2 - single quotes are giving error

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, single-quotes

I am trying to pass the sql file as input to the shell script and executing athena command inside the script. Somehow, UNIX creating single quote (') around the string (i.e. sql - select count(*) from table )

```
abc.sh <select_query.sql>

read_query=`cat select_query.sql`

dml=${read_query}
```

Here is the command --

```
aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "\"$dml\"" --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://bucket1/ --output text
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:1: mismatched input '"select count(*) from ecrmsfdc_raw.user;"' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'DESC', 'USING', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'GRANT', 'REVOKE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'CALL', 'PREPARE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'EXECUTE'}
```

If you notice above error, there are single quotes at the start/end of the select query. I've tried the following options... 
tr, eval, etc...
but still I was not able to get rid of those single quotes. Because of this quotes, the athena command is failing. Is there any easy way to remove this quotes prior to include it in the command. Please help...

Comment: What is `select_query.sql`?

Comment: The error seems to be complaining about the double-quotes that are included in the query string. Try removing the `\"` bits.